# Initialising a dictionary inside a class with inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary, oop

How to translate:

```
my_dict = {input("ENTER THE KEY: "): input("Please enter the value for the key: ")}
```

Into a class such as:

```
class StackOverflow:
      def __init__(self, key, value):
           self.key = key
           self.value = value
```

Comment: This seems to be an X Y problem. Maybe if you explain what your actually trying to achieve rather than just a hypothetical problem people might be able to suggest how to do it or a better way

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
 so = StackOverflow(key=input("enter key:"), value=input("enter value:"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data *absolutely must* come from a dictionary with a single key/value pair, then you can use the `items()` method, get the first (i.e. only) item, and unpack it with the `*` operator:

```py
my_object = StackOverflow(*list(my_dict.items())[0])
```

However, there is little point putting the data into a dictionary in the first place if you actually want it in an object. I recommend just writing it the simple, sensible way where each line of code does one thing:

```py
key = input("ENTER THE KEY: ")
value = input("Please enter the value for the key: ")
my_object = StackOverflow(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

On the basis that you've used a dictionary for the key/value pair, I'm assuming you're going to potentially have more than one key/value pair in the dictionary.

If that is the case, this would work:

```
my_dict = {input("ENTER THE KEY: "): input("Please enter the value for the key: ")}

class StackOverflow:
      def __init__(self, key, value):
           self.key = key
           self.value = value


class_objects = [StackOverflow(key=k, value=v) for k,v in my_dict.items()]

print(class_objects)
print(class_objects[0].key)
print(class_objects[0].value)
```